# best option to create simple website mockup with navigation

Tags: html

I'm trying to put together a static html website with full navigation.  In other words, I want the user to click some links and images and actually be taken to another page.  I'm a developer so I know how to do this in frameworks like ASP.Net MVC and grails.  However, for this particular case, I just want to quickly mock up the UI and provide simple navigation so I can do some user testing.  Can anyone advice on how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever heard of [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/)?
It sounds to me this is exactly what you are looking for.

It allow you to directly create your website online, already hosted, with simple drag and drop features.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need just link-tag:

```
<a href="some.html">click me</a>
```

and may be some javascript.